# Why does this CosmosDB SubQuery fail?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to use a simple subquery to get a value but I get an error about cardinality

Query as follows:

```
SELECT va.variantId AS ItemNo,
       c.Season,
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 7) AS ProductNo,
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 10) AS ArticleNo, 
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 13) AS VariantNo,
       (
        SELECT VALUE p["value"]
        FROM c
        JOIN p IN c.OriginalData.presentation.productNameLong
        WHERE c.ItemNo = '123456'
        AND p.locale = 'en-GB'
        AND c.Season = '201808'
        AND c.brand = 'xxx'
        ) AS Title
FROM c
JOIN sm IN c.OriginalData.base.sales.summary.salesMarkets
JOIN ar IN sm.articles
JOIN va IN ar.variants
JOIN ch IN va.channels
WHERE c.ItemNo = '123456'
AND sm.salesMarket = 'SE'
AND ch.channelName = 'xxx'
```

The error is as follows:

```
Failed to query item for container rawdata:
 Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":227,"end":498},"code":"SC2201","message":"The cardinality of a scalar subquery result set cannot be greater than one."}]}
ActivityId: 11ff3b08-d8a7-4737-9111-81f319cf1dc5, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0
```

The result of that subquery can only ever be 1 single result so I am not sure what it is complaining about

Comment: FYI: don't pack business needs to data access query (i.e. format strings to arrays to strings, or to substring `variantId` to pieces. It'll just cost more and scale less. Fetch data, then process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ARRAY expression to construct an array from subquery's results.

Please try this SQL:

```
SELECT va.variantId AS ItemNo,
       c.Season,
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 7) AS ProductNo,
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 10) AS ArticleNo, 
       SUBSTRING(va.variantId, 0, 13) AS VariantNo,
       ARRAY(
        SELECT VALUE p["value"]
        FROM c
        JOIN p IN c.OriginalData.presentation.productNameLong
        WHERE c.ItemNo = '123456'
        AND p.locale = 'en-GB'
        AND c.Season = '201808'
        AND c.brand = 'xxx'
        ) AS Title
FROM c
JOIN sm IN c.OriginalData.base.sales.summary.salesMarkets
JOIN ar IN sm.articles
JOIN va IN ar.variants
JOIN ch IN va.channels
WHERE c.ItemNo = '123456'
AND sm.salesMarket = 'SE'
AND ch.channelName = 'xxx'
```

Comment: LOL so I have to REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(toString(ARRAY(
        SELECT VALUE p["value"]
        FROM c
        JOIN p IN c.OriginalData.presentation.productNameLong
        WHERE c.ItemNo = '0629367'
        AND p.locale = 'en-GB'
        AND c.Season = '201808'
        AND c.brand = 'xxx'
        )), '[', ''), ']', ''), '\"', '') AS Title

In order to make an array out of a string and then convert it back to a string????? I think I better make 2 queries and handle this in the API itself